# Send Post-Request with WebView2 -> postData does not reach the API endpoint

Tags: c#, .net, http-post, webview2

I am using WebView2 (version 1.0.2365.46) in a WPF Application. I do have also a ASP.NET WebApp. I want to send a POST-Request to login in my WebApp from the WPF Application.

This is how I send the request on button click:

```
url = "https://localhost:5001/Account/LoginMachine";

var userData = new UserData()
{
    Username = "Test",
    Password = "abc"
};

var jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(userData);
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString)))
{
    var request = webView.CoreWebView2.Environment.CreateWebResourceRequest(
        url,
        "POST",
        stream,
        "Content-Type: application/json");

    webView.CoreWebView2.NavigateWithWebResourceRequest(request);
}
```

And this is how my API endpoint looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> LoginMachine([FromBody] UserData userData)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

The userData at the API entpoint is always null.

What do I have to change to receive the userData at the API endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now solved this. I had to use HttpClient for this.

These are the different steps I had to take to fulfill my requirements:

1. Set the base URL (it would be better to set it as const for the whole class. But for this example it is also ok like this.):

```
var baseUrl = "https://localhost:5001";
```

2. Clean all old cookies (just for safety):

```
var cookieListTask = webView.CoreWebView2.CookieManager.GetCookiesAsync(baseUrl);
var cookieList = await cookieListTask;

foreach (var cookie in cookieList)
{
    webView.CoreWebView2.CookieManager.DeleteCookie(cookie);
}
```

3. Create final login URL and prepare login-data:

```
var url = baseUrl + "/Account/LoginMachine";

var userData = new UserData()
{
    Username = "Test",
    Password = "abc"
};

var jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(userData);
var content = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

4. Create HttpClientHandler:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
```

5. Create HttpClient and pass the handler:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
```

6. Send request:

```
var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
```

7. If request was successfull read response data, get cookies from handler and store new cookies in your webView instance:

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    string responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    var cookies = handler.CookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri(baseUrl));
    foreach (Cookie cookie in cookies)
    {

        var tmpCookie = webView.CoreWebView2.CookieManager.CreateCookie(cookie.Name, cookie.Value, cookie.Domain, cookie.Path);

        webView.CoreWebView2.CookieManager.AddOrUpdateCookie(tmpCookie);
    }
```

8. Redirect your client:

```
webView.Source = new Uri("https://localhost:5001");
```

9. Done:

```
    }
}
```